# max_iters doesn't seem to work with GLPK_MI solver in Python

Tags: python, solver, cvxpy, glpk, cvxopt

I'm debugging my code right now and since it's running with some datas and not with other ones, I wanted to set the 'max_iters' option to 1 to see if it works in only 1 iteration or if it needs more. I realised it doesn't seem to even use it. I tried putting a string "hello" instead of an int and it even worked. Do someone knows if it's a known problem?

```
self.prob.solve(solver="GLPK_MI", max_iters=1)
```

I'm using the CVXPY module with CVXOPT.

EDIT:
I want to do this because I don't get an error, it just continues to run forever. And with the project I'm working on it can take a lot of time to run so I wonder if it's really not working or if it's just a question of time.

Comment: I would not be surprised to see that this is not even passed to the solver. What does it mean anyway? While this *iteration number* is a common concept in the more common interior-point or first-order solvers (often used in practice) which solve continuous models, it's less common (and one could argue about it's meaning) in branch-and-cut based simplex-codes. Branching-iterations? Simplex-iterations? Who knows. In BnC code, early-termination is controlled by time or mip-gap in 99.9% of all use-cases. Maybe you can pas arbr. GLPK_options (from **its** manual, cvxpy's does not know them).

Comment: Furthermore i'm wondering how some iteration number would help debugging something described as *works with some data, but not with others*. If the solver-status is checked (without surprises) i don't see any merit in changing iteration numbers. You probably want to remove part of the constraints dynamically to recognize problematic / infeasible sub-parts.

Comment: @sascha Thank you for your answer! I forgot this part but I wanted to see it because I don't get an error, it just continues to run forever. And with the project I'm working on it can take a lot of time to run so I wonder if it's really not working or if it's just a question of time. My next step is to try to run it for a week without touching it haha. I'll edit the question to add this information!

Comment: As variance is high in discrete-combination, i don't recommend waiting a week. It's quite possible that 95% of cases are solved within 3 secs, but some case is not solved in a month!. For debugging: try to use smaller datasets. Modify them (trim) or generate them yourself. Depends on the use-case. If there is no error, you should assume the solver is still searching in general. You might also look into the process manager. CPU-usage and memory-usage (which probably will grow over time). Maybe there is a chance to turn on verbose-mode,but as GLPK is wrapped behind cvxopt,this is badly documened

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be better if you set the max iterations as a variable? (just a suggestion)

In any case, in CVXOPT you need to set the max number of iteration as

```
'maxiters' : 1
```

or you can set it as a variable and then call solver as per below

```
opts = {'maxiters' : 1}
self.prob.solve(solver="GLPK_MI", options = opts)
```